# How do I get past the second boulder in the Owa Daim Shrine?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I'm in the *Owa Daima Shrine* (the Stasis Trial). I can't seem to get past the second stationary boulder. Is there an item/power I need to move it? I've only completed the Magnesis and Bomb Trials so far. How long should I sit here staring at this puzzle?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems you need to target it with [Stasis](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Stasis_Rune) and hit it repeatedly.  When time returns to normal, the boulder will roll forward from the hits you made on it when it was frozen, clearing the path.

> Freeze the stationary boulder and then repeatedly hit it. When time returns to normal the boulder will roll forwards off the platform, allowing you to progress.

<sub>[(Source)](http://www.usgamer.net/articles/legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild-how-to-find-the-owa-daim-shrine-and-complete-the-stasis-trial)</sub>

Comment: Note that there's a sledgehammer nearby.  The stone only needs one hit from the sledgehammer while time is frozen to send it flying

Comment: @Powerlord if it only takes one hit, then you don't need stasis

Comment: The one hit doesn't send it flying if it is not stasised, or break the stone.